# MS Access 2003 - Failure to create MDE file: error VBA is corrupt?

Tags: database, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

Ok so this is a brand new snag I have run into. I am trying to launch a new MDE from my source MDB file, and it is locking up Access.

So in my mdb, I am first compacting and repairing, and then selecting create a new mde (just as I have done many times before).

It looks like it is starting the process, but never gets to where it compacts when it is done, and access is not responding. So after I force close the app, I look in the folder where I am trying to create the MDE to and I see there is a new access db1 file there.

If I try to open that it gives me an error that says file not found, and then it says the Visual Basic for Applications is corrupt.

The thing is, I just made a very simple adjustment to the code since last launching an mde, and after this I double and triple checked it...its not that because its just a simple open this form and close this one addition.

I did however have my source mdb file on a disc that I copied to my laptop, and then tried to re link the tables to the network drive (had them linked to other tables on my local drive so that I could develop offline)??

PLEASE HELP!!!

Comment: Have you decompiled and / or imported everything into a fresh mdb?

Comment: yeah i solved it. i did try that though from way back when you helped me with the "too many objects". it was something weird with some code i was trying to use to remove the "access shell window" and only show the forms. i got it to work...thanks Remou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to check is whether your code compiles.  Go to the VBE window and select *Debug* from the menu, then *Compile YourProjectName* from the submenu.  If Compile is unavailable (greyed out), make any minor change (like add a blank line) to one of your code modules.  Then try the Compile menu option.  Fix any compile errors it shows you before attempting to create an MDE.

Comment: i appreciate it once again. i actually solved it, but i never even knew I could do the above, so thanks!

Comment: Code can compile and still hide corruption. Until you've decompiled, you don't know if your code really compiles or not.

Answer (score 2):

First try to work around these steps:

1. You need to create a blank database.
2. Open the corrupted database, and then click Tables under Objects.
3. Right-click the first table, and then click Export on the shortcut menu.
4. In the Export to dialog box, browse and click the newly created database.
5. Click OK. Repeat steps 3 through 4 for each table, query, and macro.

Still, if it doesn't resolve the problem then you can get it recovered using Access database repair software.

Comment: Importing will sometimes import corruption. You simply have to decompile to know you've got a healthy VBA project.